# ext js code to add number field dynamically is not showing any errors nor rendering any UI

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

It is not showing any errors nor rendering any UI.  I want to add number field dynamically.

```
var numberField= Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        cls: 'questionRows',
        hidden: show,
        itemId: item.HealthNeedsDetailsGuid,
        id: item.HealthNeedsDetailsGuid,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'field',
            html: item_index + ') ' + item.HealthNeedsQuestion
        }, {
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            anchor: '100%',
            name: 'bottles',
            clearIcon: false,
            width: 400,
            value: 99,
            maxValue: 99,
            minValue: 0
         }]
    });
```

Comment: hidden: show, if "show" is a variable then it has to be "false". You should not use ids, but only itemIds. the item with xtype 'field' is not necessary as you could use label on the numberfield (probably with labelAlign: 'top')

Answer (score 1):

In sencha touch, `Ext.form.Panel` is a **scrollable** item, so it will not be shown untill you specify a height or make `scrollable` property as `null`.

To show the number field on the entire screen, you can give `fullscreen:true` property in `Ext.form.Panel`. Like this:

```js
Ext.application({
    launch : function() {
        var numberField= Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        cls: 'questionRows',
        fullscreen:true,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'field',
           html: 'Field Html here'
        }, {
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            anchor: '100%',
            name: 'bottles',
            clearIcon: false,
            width: 400,
            value: 99,
            maxValue: 99,
            minValue: 0
         }]
    });
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.4.2/resources/css/sencha-touch.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.4.2/sencha-touch-all-debug.js"></script>
```

**OR**

To add it to an existing component call `add()` from existing component and give `numberField` as its parameter `mainPanel.add(numberField);`.
In `numberField` either give `height` property or `scrollable:null` property to the `Ext.form.Panel`. Like this:

```js
Ext.application({
    launch : function() {
        var numberField= Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        cls: 'questionRows',
        height:344,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'field',
            html: 'Field Html here'
        }, {
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            anchor: '100%',
            name: 'bottles',
            clearIcon: false,
            width: 400,
            value: 99,
            maxValue: 99,
            minValue: 0
         }]
    });
//this is the Panel we'll be adding to
var mainPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
fullscreen: true,
items: {
    html: 'Main Panel'
}
});
//now we add the numberField inside the main panel
mainPanel.add(numberField);
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.4.2/resources/css/sencha-touch.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.4.2/sencha-touch-all-debug.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Which version you are using? Need more code to understand the problem.

Comment: I am working on some old code, the version is 2.4.2, that's okay I will try to figure it out.

Comment: Are you using Sencha Touch??

Comment: Oh my bad I gave you ext js solution. I have updated my answer as per sencha touch

Comment: thanks, this is working now. But the up and down arrows are missing.